# Python error using Google Speech-to-Text API: startswith() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, google-api, speech-to-text

I am new to Python and looking to implement [this code provided by Google APIs][1] for Speech-to-Text. After adding my bucket name, I receive this error:

`TypeError: startswith() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`

I have tried converting the path function to a string and still receive the error. What am I missing? Please see my code below.

````
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Speech to text from video file', formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter
    )
    parser.add_argument('--path', help="File or GCS path for audio file to be recognized")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--model",
        help="The speech recognition model to use",
        choices=["command_and_search", "phone_call", "video", "default"],
        default="default",
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args) 
    
    path=("gs://parabilis-june-webinar")
    path.startswith().toString().startsWith("gs://example-june-webinar")

    if args.path.startswith("gs://example-webinar"):
            transcribe_model_selection_gcs(args.path, args.model)
    else:
            transcribe_model_selection(args.path, args.model)```


  [1]: https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/transcribe_model_selection.py
````

Comment: Problem is with `path.startswith().` this take atleast one argument.

Comment: That's not how `startsWith` works in any case.  Just delete that whole line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
path.startsWith("gs://example-june-webinar")
```

This will return `True` in your case which you can use for your uses case.

Comment: If you want this to be useful, you should tell him WHICH one to replace, since he has that code three times.  Even better, show him the the working code.

Comment: Responses to Tim's notes would be immensely helpful! Should "path=("gs://parabilis-june-webinar")" be retained since "path" needs to be defined?